# :map <c-n> showing multiple maps when not being set in .vimrc

Tags: key-bindings

I have this added to my vimrc

```
map <C-n> :cnext<CR>
map <C-m> :cprevious<CR>
nnoremap <leader>a :cclose<CR>
```

This is from [vim-go-tutorial](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/wiki/Tutorial#vimrc-improvements) here.

While after running a simple :GoBuild with some errors, while trying to jump to the next error, it doesn't do as intended jump to the next definition. While doing `:cnext` and then doing a `<C-m>` works and executes `:cprevious`

While in the file, I tried running `:map <c-m>` and it only shows being mapped to `:cprevious` which is why this command was working in the first place, but then when I tried doing a `:map <c-n>`, It showed me a couple of things being mapped

```
x  <C-N>       * :<C-U>call multiple_cursors#new("v", 0)<CR>
n  <C-N>       * :call multiple_cursors#new("n", 1)<CR>
os <C-N>         :cnext<CR>
```

While I don't have the other two mappings being showed in my vimrc, how do I remove these two other invocations and just have `:cnext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They were added by a plugin

It looks like these mappings are added by the [vim-multiple-cursors plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).

To prevent that plugin from overriding your `<C-n>` mapping, you can either remove the plugin (the fact that you didn't recognise it suggests you don't use it?) or [tell it not to create mappings and set up your own](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors#mapping):

```
let g:multi_cursor_use_default_mapping=0

" Default mapping
"let g:multi_cursor_start_word_key      = '<C-n>' USE SOMETHING ELSE INSTEAD
"                                         OF `<C-n>` HERE
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_word_key = '<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_start_key           = 'g<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_key      = 'g<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_next_key            = '<C-n>' AND PROBABLY HERE
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key            = '<C-p>'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key            = '<C-x>'
let g:multi_cursor_quit_key            = '<Esc>'
```

N.B. The vim-multiple-cursors GitHub page has a massive banner saying that the plugin is deprecated and that you should use [vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) instead. Note that vim-visual-multi also overrides `<C-n>` by default, but has a [different mechanism for changing the mapping it uses](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi/wiki/Mappings#customization).

### Using both sets of mappings

If you *only* want to use your `<C-n>` mapping in Go files, and want to use the vim-multiple-cursors plugin's mapping elsewhere, then you could instead set up your mappings for the Go filetype by creating the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/go` if it doesn't already exist, and then adding your mapping as a buffer-local mapping in that file:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <C-n> :cnext<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <C-m> :cprevious<CR>
```

Comment: I missed this, removing https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors worked. Thanks!